# Show ProgressDialog while inflating LARGE layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask, android-spinner, layout-inflater

I have an app which dynamically creates different forms (a layout displaying several kinds of form fields) based on jsons retrieved from server. Everything works fine, but the forms are usually quiet bit large, so it can take several seconds to inflate the whole form.

I'd like to show a `ProgressDialog` while the layout is inflated, but it will only appear correctly if I create the form inside an `AsyncTask`; sadly, I'm not able to inflate anything outside the main thread.

**Does anyone know of a workaround for this scenario?**

Comment: Are you inflating layouts, or are you dynamically creating Views? Also, could you please post some code, because I just successfully ran some quick tests with both methods.

Comment: Thanks @MikeM., I'm actually doing both. For instance, I'm instantiating some simple `Buttons`, but mostly I'm inflating (`View.inflate`) more complex custom components, which I'm guessing it's the most expensive operation. Hard to post code, the logic is pretty complex and involves several classes, I think it may be more misleading than helpful :(

Comment: Well, I created an AsyncTask subclass with a constructor that takes a Context, created a LayoutInflater from that in `doInBackground()`, inflated a layout with a null root ViewGroup, returned that to `onPostExecute()`, and passed it in a callback method to my Activity, where I added it to a pre-existing container ViewGroup. Of course, you can instantiate Views from that Context, as well. Is there something you're doing differently that's causing a problem?

Comment: Mmh maybe what I'm doing wrong is trying to add the new layouts as subviews inside `doInBackground` instead of `onPostExecute`. I'd need to do several changes to do it that way, but it's worthy to try. Thanks!

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, then yeah, that's most likely the problem. You don't wanna pass an existing ViewGroup into `doInBackground()`. Create the layout as an "orphan", then add it after you've passed it back to the UI thread. Cheers!